# How to execute jobs in sequence?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, quartz.net

I my WebApi project I save information about recurring jobs in a database. One piece of information is the recurrence in the form of the standard `RRULE`.

I can convert the RRULE and the get the occurrence for the current date.

I need to use `Quartz.Net` to add these jobs (for the day) and then make them execute sequentially. I do not know which jobs might run.

Is is possible to achieve this with `Quartz.Net`?

Comment: If you have the RRULE you can dynamically create a trigger configured with the occurrence date and time. Sounds like a SimpleTrigger is what you're after: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html

Comment: That will work as I have a precomputed fixed time. Now I need a way to execute jobs in sequence.

Comment: Right, so do you mean that the one task shouldn't start before the previous one finished? If you have the precomputed times and the tasks are scheduled one after the other, they will execute in sequence, based on their scheduled time.